# Area Circle Overlay

Tags: android, geolocation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

How do I draw a area circle overlay underneath a marker?

For instance you would give the area circle an origin coordinate (Latitude, Longitude) and a radius relative to the origin.

So when you zoom in and out of the map the circle will scale with the zoom level correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard Overlay in osmdroid for that, but it's quite easy to implement that by copying and simplifying this one: [DirectedLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/DirectedLocationOverlay.java)

Comment: After hours of searching... thank you ! For those who want to use this class only to show accuracy, remove the 3 last lines in the `draw` method